# Highcart reflow function when using as a polymer component

Tags: highcharts, polymer-1.0

I'm using a polymer seed UI application, in which I needed to display some graphs so decided to use high charts. I created a custom component and added one of the charts e.g. barcharts and added this polymer component to my seed application do display the bar charts.

I am able to view the charts correctly, however, I faced an know issue of rendering the charts which didn't fit the container. In order to resolve it, I need to use highcart.reflow() event. But I don't know on which lifecycle of polymer I should do it and it will resize the charts correctly on page load.

any help is appreciated

Comment: I would use `ready` or `attached`, from [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#lifecycle-callbacks).

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work